# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:

Tags: exception, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have generated classed using JAXB from this xsd file

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://testwork/"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://testwork/">
    <xs:element name="sayHelloWorldFrom" type="tns:sayHelloWorldFrom"/>
    <xs:element name="sayHelloWorldFromResponse" type="tns:sayHelloWorldFromResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="sayHelloWorldFrom">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="sayHelloWorldFromResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the generated class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sayHelloWorldFrom", namespace = "http://testwork/", propOrder = {
    "arg0"
})
public class SayHelloWorldFrom {

    protected String arg0;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the arg0 property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getArg0() {
        return arg0;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the arg0 property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setArg0(String value) {
        this.arg0 = value;
    }

}
```

I have a soap message just like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testwork/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>?</arg0>
      </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to format this message into class SayHelloWorldFrom, here is the example of my code

```
public void unmarshalSoapRequest(InputStream is) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext js = JAXBContext.newInstance(SayHelloWorldFrom.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = js.createUnmarshaller();
        SayHelloWorldFrom sayHelloWorldFrom = (SayHelloWorldFrom)   unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
```

But I have an error in Tomcat logs like

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope"
). Expected elements are (none)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please, help newbie :-)
Thanx in advnance

Comment: The following will help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to unmarshall a stream that contains SOAP specific information using a JAXB context that knows nothing about SOAP. It is only able to unmarshall the middle of the SOAP request.

```
  <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <arg0>?</arg0>
  </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
```

You are not supposed to write the `unmarshalSoapRequest` method. Normally, you'd either to create a class that implements your Web service interface or to write a WSDL and generate the code from the WSDL not from the XSD.